# AWS - deny services deployment in public subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We are building some security boundaries for our internal teams and would like to limit their ability to deploy services in Public Subnets.
I can build a boundary policy for EC2 not to be deployed in public subnets but this only covers EC2 service. Is there a way to block all services, existing or future, from being deployed in a specific subnet?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every resource needs an **ENI - Elastic Network Interface**. Therefore can try to restrict ENI creation in your public subnets. That will cover EC2, RDS, Fargate, VPC-Lambda, ELB/ALB, etc. Not sure if it's possible to create an IAM policy like that, I haven't tried.

In any case **[AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/)** will notice when a new ENI has been created and you can act upon that. Check out **[Use AWS Config Rules to Automatically Remediate Non-compliant Resources](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/use-aws-config-rules-to-automatically-remediate-non-compliant-resources/)**.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you , I will check it out!